# Can I see which comments I flagged?

Tags: support

In my profile, under *Flags* I see the **posts** I flagged. Now I want to see which **comments** I flagged and don't find them. Am I too blind to see the obvious?

Comment: I've never figured out how to view them either.

Comment: I think they regard comment flags as too insignificant to warrant mention. Comment votes don't do a thing, why should flags matter either? (I do kind of wish that you could view that list, though...)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude, well comment flags can be (not) deemed helpful, they can be rejected, so they are not **that** insignificant it seems :-)

Comment: @guntbert Yeah, I agree that they should be able to be viewed; I was just explaining the current situation and the reasoning (however illogical) behind it.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude, no worries :-)

Comment: Comment flags are now shown in your flagging history, with a link to the comment (although not the text).

Comment: @Seth True, I am sure that has been the case for some time now - although I couldn't tell since **when**.

Comment: Same time this happened: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6970/am-i-the-first-person-to-be-privileged-with-100-flags-for-the-day/6972#6972