# Am I the first person to be privileged with 100 flags for the day?

Tags: support, flags

I have been on and off the Stack Exchange network for the last couple of days and hence have not been able to raise the usual number of flags that I often raise. With last flagged post on 17th June; I thought about raising some flags for our dear moderators - and I am allowed to raise 100 flags for the day (sorry, the image shows 99 - I took the screenshot after flagging one of the posts):

> [image: flag dialog]

Previously, as far as I remember, I had about 42 normal flags and about 37/38 spam and offensive flags. Right now, the total of 100 counts towards both normal and spam/offensive flags.

Is this some special privilege alloted to me for my absence for the last few days? My permanent flag count? A bug?

Has any other user ever had the privilege to flag the maximum of 100 posts?

PS: My flag count on Meta and other SE network sites is normal as it should be.

Comment: I thought I was the only one! http://i.stack.imgur.com/aIDAE.png

Comment: @jokerdino: But you are a mod!! That flag count is useless in your case ;)

Comment: I got this via Shog - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890

Comment: @jokerdino: Ah thanks... missed that question on MSO... I only searched the questions tagged as [flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jarrod Dixon, a developer for Stack Exchange, said [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185866/flag-count-is-missing-from-profile-pages/185889#comment570008_185889) that comment flags weren't being counted correctly before; so in the new build your flag count *includes* comment flags (if that makes any sense..)

Comment flags now appear in your flag history as well.

Answer (score 8):

As it looks, you are so awesome, the SE system awarded you with 100 flags which makes you an
**H** onorary **A** skUbuntu **V** ery **E** xtensive **F** lagger with **U** tter **N** oticeableness

Since I am a mod I am doomed to stay like this forever and suffer from the weight of knowing I will never be able to finish them all on time...EVER!:

[image]

PS: I think the whole system just got reset/updated and everyone now has/starts with 100 flags.